# How to test an AJAX application that is pulling data from a live website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, testing, cross-domain

I'm working on an AJAX application that pulls data from a live website, I can't replicate the complete application on my local environment at the moment so in order to test if the JavaScript code is working as expected I need to be able to bypass the same domain restriction on the browser (without making changes on the webserver) any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

So far I have tried modifying the `prefs.js` in Firefox 2 and Camino including the lines suggested in this link: http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/08/30/cross-domain-xhr-with-firefox/

Thanks in advance.

*Edit 04/29/2009 3:18pm:*

I agree the proxy option is definitely a way to go. But would it be possible to have a solution using just Firefox? (maybe an add-on?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the endpoint URL you could bounce the requests through your local server, either with mod_rewrite or a simple script.

This has the advantage that you can easily log the requests and responses, and alter them (e.g. send back timeout errors, bad data and the like).

Comment: +1 I think this is the way to go.  You could write a simple, stand-alone proxy that lets you switch 'modes' at will.  For several of our projects, we had a proxy that could switch between 'normal', 'slow', 'timeout', etc from a simple command line interface.

Comment: I agree the proxy option is definitely a way to go. But would it be possible to have a solution using just Firefox (maybe an add-on?)
Actually if there is not, it could be a nice extension to try to write and might be helpful to a lot of people, something like an integrated proxy on the browser.

Comment: Although Fiddler is a stand-alone proxy, it has some sort of FF plug-in in the latest beta. Not sure if the plugin is just an on/off switch, but communicating more info wouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score -1):

Well, for viewing the requests/stepping through the js try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I don't think this applies here.  It sounds like he can't even make the request because his development machine is on a different domain than the data provider.  The browser's cross-domain restrictions keep him from ever making the request.

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer, that is correct. There is no request going on because of the restriction.